# CloudWatch Rule won't trigger Lambda Function, even with correct permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create rules with BOTO3, but even when the rules are targeted to the lambda function, it still won't trigger them at all.

It can trigger the rule but fails invocation every time.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating them `CloudWatch Event Rules` programmatically, So you need to add the necessary permissions as well when to allow `CloudWatch` to invoke your lambda.

Below is the resource-based policy added to lambda to allow cloudwatch event rule named `mycustomrule` to invoke lambda named `mynode`

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSEvents_mycustomrule_Id6319267638851",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345678990:function:mynode",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:12345678990:rule/mycustomrule"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you did not provide much information on what is happening, this is my first guess from your post.

[Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Comment: How exactly is this added to the lambda? When trying to add a resource based policy I get a form, not something I can input JSON into

Comment: @peadarx1 not sure how you are adding trigger for lambda, in the OP you mentioned it is done via `boto3` , but now you are mentioning the behaviour of `console` .  If you check the link I added in the answer you can add the necessary permissions which will result into something like above via CLI as described in the doc attached. If you are doing via `console` when you can do it via either the form you are getting or go to `cloudwatch` service and there it will ask you like this `CloudWatch Events will add necessary permissions for target(s) so they can be invoked when this rule is triggered.`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SXR8JU1 This is my current policy document. Is this not the same as your one?

Comment: @peadarx1 yes, that's the correct policy. Just a side note,  try not to expose your account-related information.

Comment: I really can't understand why it is failing invocation like this. When I manually add a trigger online it works fine but programmatically it just fails everytime

Comment: @peadarx1 It is just a matter of getting the permissions correct it works all the time. You can keep the things running and try to generate the policy, once it is what you want, deploy.